# List<ListviewItem>

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me the meaning and the usage of `List<ListViewItem>`?

And also the difference between `ListviewItem` and `List<ListViewItem>`?

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) a ListViewItem is an object that

> "Represents an item in a ListView
>   control."

The List<ListViewItem> is a (non-UI related) List of ListViewItems.

See the [List<T> documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) at MSDN for an explanation of those, but it's  essentially a useful .NET collection of a specified type of item (in this case ListViewItem).

Answer (score 4):

List<> is a generic list. By putting a type like ListViewItem in the brackets you tell the clr to create a new type that is specifically a list of of ListViewItems. ListViewItem could easily be replaced by another type - say string, to create a list those types, say `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the second one is a List that consists of ListViewItem where as ListviewItem is just an individual item.